# Tool for comparing web.config files

Tags: visual-studio, web-config

Is there a good tool to compare *specifically* web.config files to find specifically which settings are different values and which file has settings that don't appear in both.

XML comparison should do the trick, or an XSLT might work. There must be a tool for web.config settings out there?

Comment: It looks like most people are missing the "specifically web.config" part of this question...

Comment: it looks like you are missing that that fact is irrelevant to a file comparer

Comment: I disagree with that, comparing two files that are in the same format, order, spacing etc work fine for code and other files most of the time.

I have a web.config file that has been mangled over the years, and is VERY different in ordering and sections.  What I need to see the difference in their function.  Tried out araxis merge which is great software, but doesn't shows me all kinds of false negatives for missing assemblies simply because they are in a different order.

Comment: Yes, exactly what zimmer62 said. IMO, any solution that says includes a caveat like, "if you format both your files" greatly lessens the usefulness of the tool for the purpose of comparing web.configs. I don't see any suitable solutions here. I do use diff, but it only does so much.

Comment: General file comparers are dumb. They don't perform functional comparison. They perform line-by-line diffs, which are generally useless. Content-aware comparisons are much more useful. Two files such as a web config, can be functionally equivalent, while appearing completely different to a line-by-line comparer.  Just because the file type is text-based, doesn't mean a line-by-line diff tool is useful for it.

Comment: For example when looking for duplicate images, you would want a content-aware comparer that would tell you when two files represent the same image even though one is rotated 90 degrees. A bitwise comparison tool is useless. Same is true for webconfig files. The order of the application keys doesn't matter, so a true functional diff tool would be able to recognize they contain the same app setting keys with the same values even if they're in a different order. The FatAntelope tool below is a real gem, because it's such a specific domain and we're lucky it exists.  It's probably one of a kind.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

https://github.com/CameronWills/FatAntelope 
This tool will compare two web.config files and generate a web.config transform from the difference.

Disclaimer:
I wrote it... I wanted to compare two web.config files and generate a transform. But I couldn't find anything out to help much beyond standard text file diff tools (WinMerge etc) which dont work very well for XML. So I created one :)

Comment: This question was posted seven years ago, rules were different by then. As a matter of fact, the question is now closed - no new answers will be allowed. Preventing questions from being asked is impossible. If you have further inquiries, feel free to [drop into chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers).

Comment: Sounds awesome! I will surely try it. :)

Comment: 7 years old, but still relevant when you have to look after old systems with out-of-sync web.configs. I will try your solution and give you some points!

Comment: Very, very relevant. Switching cloud platforms, needing to coordinate web configs between source code and tenant-specific deployment directories... this tool is a TREASURE.

Answer (score 4):

[BeyondCompare](http://www.scootersoftware.com/moreinfo.php) amongst many other utils

Comment: BeyondCompare isNOT free.. as far as i know. isnt it?

Comment: Nice tool though! I think Jeff Atwood has mentioned this on the SO Podcast.

Comment: Well if it isn't free the licence expiry code is buggy :)

Comment: who downvotes beyond compare?

Answer (score 4):

[WinMerge](http://winmerge.org/downloads/) will help you best if you format both your files... you can format in Visual Studio itself and then compare in WinMerge...

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, Araxis merge is the best tool for comparing any documents:

http://www.araxis.com/merge/index.html

Use it myself at work.

Answer (score 0):

**Use diff**

It will neatly point out the exact lines and text that is different.

[Diff Utilities](http://www.gnu.org/software/diffutils/diffutils.html) are available for windows as well. [**Download here**.](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/diffutils.htm)

Comment: Let's just say the config files aren't sorted in the same way, a diff tool won't show this as well as a bespoke web.config file difference tool might.

Answer (score 0):

Wikipedia has a [comparison of file comparison tools](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_comparison_tools). Take your pick :o)

Comment: yeah.. the word comparison is in that sentance too often!

Answer (score 0):

Use [winmerge](http://winmerge.org/).

You should get used to version control, subversion and [tortoisesvn](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) are recommended, and [ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)  provides svn access from Visual Studio.